# How to link two news page multilingual press

Tags: posts, multisite

I have two sites one in English and one in Finnish

I have post page for English as News
and Finnish as Uutiset

I was able to link single news posts from news to uutiset and vice versa but when I tried to link the page News to Uutiset it is not working it takes me to home page.

The plugin I am using is mutlilingual Press

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: There is no code to post, Its the setting with the plugin. I can link all other pages to their corresponding finnish pages but being unable to link the news pages (which is the post page) to its finnish post page which is Uutiset.

Comment: I just want to do this

NEWS -> UUTISET
UUTISET --> NEWS

I could do the same thing for all other static pages but for this post page its not working its taking me to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of Multilingual Press. Currently, there is no user interface to connect existing posts. This will be possible in one of the next versions.

You can either connect both in the table `$wpdb->base_prefix . 'multilingual_linked'` or create a new post as the translation for the other.

Comment: Is there any way to do this, Not connecting the existing pages or posts but something like this.

Create NEWS page ( which is post page of english site)
Create UUTISET page as NEWS pages' translation page ( which is post page of the finnish site)

And then start adding posts to NEWS pages and translation posts.

Please help.

Comment: @frederim This works by default. Translate the parent pages first, then the hierarchy of the child pages will stay intact on both sites.